# What is the difference accessing root folders as /$ and as /#?

Tags: 14.04

From user home directory, when I run "cd .." continuously, it takes me to the prompt with /$ and when I ls here, it lists all root folders. When i run "sudo -s" or "sudo -i" or "sudo su", it takes me to the prompt with /# and when I ls here also, it lists all root directories. What is the difference accessing these root folders as /$ and  as /# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your prompt says `/$`, you are logged in as your user. You have your user's permissions.

When your prompt says `/#` you are logged in as `root` and have a much more elevated set of permissions, and can make more changes on the system.

The directories are still the same ones.

The different character at the end of your prompt is a clue that says: "You're working as as root"

Comment: The $ # characters are just a convention, set up as the last character in your/root prompt, environment variable PS1, in your .bashrc file.

Comment: Correct, but I'm presuming OP is using the defaults.

Answer (score 3):

In this case not so much. `ls` in itself is pretty harmless.

There are a couple of things:

- doing something with a `$` as a prompt will log events as your user.
- doing something with a `#` as a prompt after doing `sudo -i` will log events as your user.
- doing something with a `#` as a prompt after doing `sudo -u` will log events as "root".

The last one should be avoided on multi user systems so you trace an action back to a user. On a single user system it is good practice to copy this behaviour: you can then trace an action back to you or to a "root" driven event (like services log as root so you can see it was not you that did something).

The problem when using `sudo -i` and `sudo -u` are related to other commands. Like `rm` and `dd` and a couple more where the system will execute these commands without informing you something bad is about to happen. bad as in something you did not expect. A normal user would get a warning about permissions and the command will fail.

Action done with a root user are also executed as root. So if you copy a file over to another location and forget to set the correct permissions your user account will not get access. And we have a couple of files on our systems that need specific permissions for the system to function. Mess with those and you lock yourself out. Those problems can be solved with a grub rescue or a live session so it merely annoying and not permanent.

Comment: Correct, which is why the best practice is `sudo -i`